# Retrieving messages from status table in FQL using PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I am developing a php script for retrieving messages from a page (not user) in facebook. I have access to that page (it is mine) so if I must to modify something in config, I can.

I tried the FQL query in graph api webpage from Facebook and it works. I get the file with all messages.

But whenever I try it in my php script, it fails. I am trying it in a localhost server and calling the script : "localhost/testServer/phpScript.php" I don't know if I have to add a parameter.

I have checked many examples and tutorials and all are similar but in my case, they don't work.

I always get an exception with this message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 100: Requires user session thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\testServer\base_facebook.php on line 1271
```

If I surround it in try/catch and print what I get, it tells it is an exception with getType() and an array with getResult().

My code is quite simple:

```
<?php

require_once("facebook.php");

//Get Facebook SDK Object
$config = array(
  'appId'  => '*******',
  'secret' => '*******',
  'cookie' => true,
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

//$fql = "SELECT message FROM status WHERE uid = 169070991963 ORDER BY time DESC";
$fql = "SELECT message FROM status WHERE uid = 169070991963";

//Create Query
$param  =   array(
    'method'    => 'fql.query',
    'query'     => $fql,
    'access_token'=>'*******|******-*******',
    'ext_perm'   => "read_stream",
);
    $result = $facebook->api($param);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

I just deleted my appId, secret and access_token.

I read something about read_stream permissions using status table. But adding access_token and ext_perm tags has no effect. I leave the uid of the webpage because it is public so you can test the code on your own.

If I can't do this query with php fql, I have no problem in using normal api if I can get the same result.

I am expending many days doing this script and I am completely lost with the problem.

Comment: The `ext_perm` parameter that you are trying to pass to the api method does not exist. Permissions to _ask for_ have to be passed via the `scope` parameter during login flow.

Comment: can you give an example of scope? I read about it but what I tried didn't work.

Comment: If you are unclear about how the login flow works, then please consult the official FB documentation. And then ask again if you have specific problems with your code concerning that.

Comment: I don't have login flow. Do I need login flow to solve my problem?

Comment: Well you should be able to get all public posts of the page with a simple app access token (unless the page is restricted in any way – country-wise, alcohol-related, etc.) – otherwise, you’ll need an access token of a user able to se those posts, or a page access token. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/ (But it’s not necessary to request an app access token as described there, the combination `app_id|app_secret` with a pipe symbol in the middle works as app access token as well.)

Comment: I try with my user instead my facebook page and I changed the access_token I was using by one given by api graph explorer. Now I get this error: Uncaught Exception: 146: Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument thrown 

How and where do I have to set the access_token and the login?

Comment: I am getting the same error.  added this line to $param: 'scope' =>  'read_stream, user_activities',

Can you test my code with other appId and other secret to see if it works? I don't know how to use my user (for example) to get access...